# How can I return a string from one DataFrame, using a string from another?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd be glad if you'll help me with this.
I have two DataFrames. As you can see, the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMpss.png) is just a row with coordinates. The [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymt9M.png) is a table of coordinates and names of atoms. So I just want to return a similar row from the second DataFrame, using the first one. How can I do that?

Comment: The question isn't clear enough. Similiar according to what?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to return the atom row from the second dataframe using the coordinates from the row of the first dataframe? If so, you can use something like this:

```
df2.loc[df2['x'] == x_value_from_df1]
```

This will return the row from the second dataframe where the x column is equal to the value that you can supply from the first dataframe (x_value_from_df1). You can supply either the x, y or z values and this will work as well, as there seems to be no repeats in the link that you provided.